# wpf forms not displaying images

Tags: c#, css, wpf, visual-studio

I am using VS 2013 and designing a WPF form. The problem is when i design the button with image it displays perfectly but when i run the project it isn't displaying the images over button.

**Code**

```
  <Button x:Name="btnCommunication"  Margin="428,138,448,338" Click="btnCommunication_Click"  Width="Auto"  Foreground="#FF007EFF">

                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" Width="350">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,-80,41" Source="Images/communication.png" Width="135" Height="195"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.525,0.37"  />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0,174,-128,30" Text="Communication Mode" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="28" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                </Grid>


            </Button>
```

Hope for help !!

Comment: I think your should check your sources of images

Comment: i have checked them. They are all correct

Comment: Right click on image, properties and set them as content. You also need to set that they should be copied to the output directory.

Comment: thanks :) it worked (y)

Answer (score -1):

I cleared the Margin and it was OK for me! 
Using margin is not a good way for Layering!
For Layering It's better to use Layering elements.Such as StackPanel and etc.